# User Content Posts

Tags: nodes, forms, users

Iam new in drupal. Now i build my first Content-Type for an Image Blog.

How to make these Content-Type available also for registred Users to submit their own Posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to enable authenticated users to create that content (in permissions).

And make relevant links (`node/add/<content-type>`) available to them

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm assuming you haven't created any user roles beyond the default roles. IF that is the case then, assuming you are using D7 go to admin/people/permissions and find the permissions related to the content type you created. Set them to be able to be created by authorized user.

I believe D8 is a similar thing.